# Dustjs helper for frontend

Tags: sails.js, dust.js

So I am using `Dustjs` on `Sailsjs` for my project.

I am rendering the first page on the server, and then use the same template client-side.

Problem: My template contains a `global sails service` which doubles as a `dustjs helper`:

> {#sails.services.globalutils.hyphenator str=title/}

But, on the `client-side`, I am unable to uyse this service. How can I export this service to the client without going for a JS solution? Can it be bundled with the dustjs template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `{#section}` signals that Dust should look in the context provided to `dust.render()`. So as long as the `hyphenator` function doesn't have server-side dependencies, you can just bring it along in your client-side context. Sails services are just Javascript modules in the `api/services` folder, so try `require`ing the relevant module, grabbing its `hyphenator` property, and passing that along to the client to use in the client's `render` call.

```
{
  "sails": {
    "services": {
      "globalutils": {
        "hyphenator": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
          // do some hyphenation
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, if `hyphenator` has logic that relies on the server, you can't just move it to the client. You could expose a server-side API that your script calls, and couple that with `chunk.map` to create an asynchronous Dust block.

Comment: This never ocurred to me ! Thanks.